# Getting date to by in 'XX format for chart

Tags: excel

I have data formatted as follows:

```
Year:  Value
2002     4
2004     8
2010     3
...
```

When I plot the data the x axis tick marks are labeled as follows:
2002, 2004, 2010.

I would like them to be '02, '04, and '10.
However, when I change the custom format to yy, they all get switched to 05 (each tick mark has the same value).

How do I fix this to get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your years that you entered in your cells are actually Excel date serial.  Ie when you change the date format on the cells do they display differently?  2010 can be the number 2010 not the year 2010.  As such enter your dates as 2010/01/01 or what ever pattern matches your system.  Just make sure that it is an actual date.  Once you have done that you can then apply the custom formatting.

[image]

Note the year in cells C2:C4 are actually 2002/01/01, 2004/01/01, 2010/01/01 with custom format yyyy so that only the year is displayed.

Sequence:

1)  Enter your years as years/month/date or whatever your system format is in your spreadsheet.
2)  Format your spreadsheet to display YYYY in custom format so only the year is display (this is purely for aesthetics)
3)  Create your XY scatter plot
4)  Format your X axis
5)  On the right side of your screen scroll down to the bottom and expand the NUMBER menu.
6)  In the Category box, select custom.
7)  In the format code box, enter yy
8)  Scroll up to the top and set you bounds minimum to the days since January 1 1900 for the first day of the year you want to look at. (enter the yyyy/mm/dd, or what matches your system, in some cell and then change it format to general.  The number displayed is the number of days)
9)  Under units, set major to 365 or 365.25 and this should keep your intervals at roughly 1 year.  The longer the spread in years the slightly weird appearance your graph may have for 365 option.

Comment: Did you set you max and min values on your X axis?  Are you using a scatter plot or a line graph?

Comment: Yes, and scatter plot

Comment: Maybe a better question is, what format code I need to display only the last two digits of a number?

Comment: Also, values with the same year are not getting stacked on to of each other. As you can see in your plot above, 2002,4 is getting plotted at 1.5

Comment: that is because the first tick is actually at 01/04/19.  Since we are only displaying year level accuracy, you would need to manually set your minimum X value to 36892.  That is the number of days since January 1 1900 which is equal to 2001/01/01.  the bigger problem you face is how to get each tick to line up. if you set your ticks to be 365 apart you will miss out on a day every 4 years roughty.  you could try 365.25 for tick spacing.

Comment: When I make the ticks all like this: 01/01/02 01/01/04 01/01/10 they still do the same thing. How do I fix that?

Comment: I added a sequence to the bottom of my answer hope it helps.  I will not be around for several hours due to a social commitment. Let me know how it works out for you.